# Xamarin.forms SwitchCell Text Does not appear fully

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am newer with **Xamarin.Forms**. Is there a way to display all text an a `SwitchCell`? The long text get's cut off.

```cs
NewsLetterSwitchCell = new SwitchCell
{
    Text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz123456789aabbccdeeffgghhjjkkllmmmnnooppqqrrsssrtg",                                        
};
NewsLetterSwitchCell.OnChanged += switcher_Toggled;
TableView tb = new TableView();
tb.Root = new TableRoot() {
    new TableSection("Enter Optional Information (* Required Fields)") {
        NewsLetterSwitchCell                
    }
};
Content = new StackLayout
{
    Children = { tb }
};
```

This Picture shows the result from my mobile. It contains only the first letters.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own custom renderer for this purpose .
Below link can help you .
[Forum link for custom switch](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24844/text-aligment-and-color-in-switchcell)